# container width much larger then content

Tags: javascript, css, width

I have a bunch of content that floats left in a container, and I'd like for the container to hug the content, but for some reason it's much wider then the content and I have no idea why.  I have it set up in a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/vG8NY/6/ the red and blue bordered containers should hug the right edge of the circle.

The code is very simple and is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="hot_spot-container">
    <div class="content-spot">
        <img class="hotspot-cir" src="http://www.klossal.com/sixred/discovery/images/hotspot-left.png" />
        <div class="hotspot-content"></div>
        <img class="hotspot-cir" src="http://www.klossal.com/sixred/discovery/images/hotspot-right.png" />
        <br class="clear-fix" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hot_spot-container {border:1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
}
.content-spot {
     border:1px solid red;
     display:inline-block;
}


.hotspot-cir {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
.hotspot-content {
    float:left;
    background:#ec6e47;
}
.clear-fix {
    clear:both;
}
```

JS

```
$(".content-spot").css({
    height:$(window).height() * ".2"    
});
```

Comment: couldn't understand what the problem you are having....

Comment: why don't you set a width in the $(".content-spot")?

Comment: if you look at the fiddle there is a orange circle sitting in a container, the container is much wider then the circle and I can't figure out why.

Comment: because shouldn't you just be able to have the container take the width of the content?

Comment: do you want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vG8NY/9/

Comment: that's closer, I want it to be flush with the circle.  Isn't there a way to do this with out setting an explicit width?  I don't understand why there is that extra width on the right side?  That width seems arbitrary (not yours, in my original)?

Comment: It looks flush to me apart from the border around the internal element.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".content-spot").css({
    height:$(window).height() * ".2",
    width:$(window).height() * ".2"
});
```

when you change height of `content-spot` it's width still fixed and need to get resize too.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/vG8NY/10/)

---

you can use this code too:

```
$(".hotspot-cir").css({
    height:$(window).height() * ".2"    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/vG8NY/13/)

Comment: there's no way to set just the height and then have the width just be the width of the content it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You must define the width for the element to which you have set the `position: absolute;` so you should use something like this:

```
.hot_spot-container {border:1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    /* any width you want or if you don't know the width then define auto.*/
    width: 45px; 
}
```

Comment: width:auto will also do

Comment: No it does not work when its loading only after its loaded my bad

Comment: how do you get it to do width:auto after it's loaded?

Answer (score 0):

if you make

```
.hot_spot-container {display:inline-block}
```

instead of it having position:absolute it does what you want it to. if you want position absolute you need to give it a width

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vG8NY/12/)

I removed your javascript and made this changes

```
.content-spot {
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

.hot_spot-container {
    border:1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```